# php - when session variables saved?

Tags: php, session, server, save, session-variables

in this example:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
echo "Session variables are set.";
?>
```

When exactly does php save the session variables into the file? When the response has been send or right after a value is assigned to the associative array?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: On completion of execution of the script, or when you explicitly execute a `session_write_close()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP saves the session data automatically at the end of your scripts runtime. You can however, force it do so early by using `session_write_close()` 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php